# Time subtraction & conditional formatting in Google Sheets

Tags: time, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm working on a simple 3-column table for logging sleep hours. It's based on "went to bed" time (col 1), "woke up" time (col 2) and "time in bed" (col 3).

All 3 columns are formatted as - `h:mm` - and Google seems to calculate the time difference correctly, considering that it has to subtract "backwards", as in "woke up" time minus "went to bed" time.

The problem arises when I add conditional formatting to the "time in bed" column. What I want is the hours spent in bed in green if >= 8:00:00 or in orange if < 8:00:00.

Adding the date as well to the "went to bed" time and "woke up" time didn't help.

The `ABS` function on the difference didn't help either.

When "time in bed" is >= 8:00:00 AND "went to bed" time happens to be BEFORE midnight, I see an orange number, where I should see a green one

Every other case works as expected.

Comment: @player0 here you go:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v4DevXMgLFjWkXjeh30OaKoJN3TSTgidkOth_IDQmX4/edit#gid=0

Comment: @player0 Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

custom formula for green color:

```
=IF(TIMEVALUE(D4)>=0.33,1)
```

[image: 0]